# when is the average of a function with Gaussian inputs bounded away from zero

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gaussian

Define a function $\phi(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Consider the expected value function defined as follows
\begin{align*}
\mu(\beta)=E[g\phi
(\beta g)]\quad with \quad g\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)\quad\text{and}\quad\beta>0
\end{align*}
I am interested in sufficient conditions on $\phi$ that ensures $|\mu(\beta)|>0$ for $\beta>0$. Another way to state my question is for what functions is it true that $\mu(1)>0$ implies $|\mu(\beta)|>0$ for $\beta>0$.

To clarify the question further note that this property is satisfied for

$\phi(x)=max(0,x)$

$\phi(x)=tanh(x)$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x\le 0$

$\phi(x)=log(1+e^x)$

$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

$\phi(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x\le 0$

what regularity condition is satisfied in all these cases? I'm looking for a general property that is shared by these functions.

Comment: As stated, the question is as good as a request  to describe (in what terms????) all functions with strictly positive Laplace transform. Unless you want a trivial answer of the kind "it is positive if and only if it is positive", you'd better specify what kind of conditions you are looking for or, even better, what the actual problem you are facing is.

Comment: Thanks, I know that the sufficient conditions is a bit vague. I do really want to keep it as general as possible. But I am looking for non-trivial possible answers. I am hoping a regularity condition of some sort is enough like if the function is continuous and sufficiently smooth in someway. Or the function increases in a particular way, is monotonic in a particular way, etc.

Comment: Yes, of course, there *are* millions of "regularity conditions of some sort" that ensure that $\int_{\mathbb R}\varphi(x)e^{-sx^2}>0$ for all $s>0$. This is exactly what makes the question unanswerable as posed. It is like a request "please, give me a ball" followed by "Nope, this one is too small; this one is too hard, this one is too soft, etc." instead of just saying "I want to play tennis". To illustrate what I mean, let us try this game for a second. All integrals are positive if $\varphi$ is a sum of a non-negative function and the Fourier transform of a non-negative measure. .

Comment: ok so let me narrow it down further. I've added some further clarification to the question.

Comment: "what regularity condition is satisfied in all these cases?" $\phi(x)+\phi(-x)\ge 0$. Note BTW that 2 and 5 are odd functions, so the expectation in question is actually $0$ for them contrary to what you requested.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to mention that 2 and 5 are zero when x is negative corrected

Comment: I am confused about phi(x)+phi(-x)>=0 condition as the all zero function also obeys this

Comment: You should add "and the inequality is strict on a set of positive measure" to get a sufficient condition, of course. I was just confused with 2 and 5 and decided that $\mu \ge 0$ might be fine for you too in view of those.

Comment: Thanks, I realized I had another typo I forgot a g in the expectation this is maybe why this was obvious before

Comment: What's the difference between denoting a function $\phi(x)$ and denoting it $x\phi(x)$? The same condition still covers all your examples only now it reads $x\phi(x)-x\phi(-x)\ge 0$ (with strict inequality on a set of positive measure, as before).

Comment: @fedja I think what the OP had in mind is some sort of things like $\frac{1}{t}W(\frac{\tau}{t})$ for a standard Brownian motion but I have never seen a related proposition like that before.